# Why memory accesses per instruction = 1+loads/stores?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I'm a student and I read a book about Computer Architecture. There is a fomula:
Memory accesses per instruction = 1 + the rate of loads/stores
I understand number 1 in this formula, but I can't understand why this is the rate of loads/stores instead of loads+stores?
I feel grateful to you for explaining me this problem!

Comment: They probably mean `+`, i.e. the rate of loads and stores combined.

Comment: loads/stores is just a short way of writing loads *or* stores.  It's an English thing, not a math operator.  (Of if this is a CISC ISA where a single instruction can involve more than one data memory operation, like x86-64 `push qword [rdi]` or `add [rdi], eax` load+store on the same location.  Then yes 1 + loads + stores, loads *and* stores.)